# Is there any MSBuild target that is executed after publishing a .NET web application?

Tags: iis, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, publish, target

I need to execute a command after publishing a .NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2019.

I tried following custom target in .csproj and .pubxml, but nothing gets printed after publish happens:

[image]

Comment: @LexLi, as it is clearly written that executing a command after publishing is what I am trying to do and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From your description**, I think you are using a Net Framework web project. **Since** **Framework web publish** does not contain the default target called `Publish`. But **Net Core web publish** has it.

For **Net Framework web publish**, it is special. **There is no such target that runs after the generation of the publish folder. It means that all the targets under the framework web publish are like BeforePublish.** It is quite annoying.

**Compared** with net core web publish, the old framework web publish does have many defects.

**However**, I have a function that can make the target executes after the generation of the publish folder.

**Solution**

**1) First**, you should install a nuget package called [MSBuild.Extension.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Extension.Pack/) which is an extra extension for msbuild tasks.

**It** has a task called `AsyncExec` which can executes with the following targets. While it is running, it will continue to execute the next steps of publish. You only need to make the command sleep for a while and wait the publish folder to be generated so that you can modify the conent of the **publish** folder..

**2)** write this under `xxx.pubxml` file:

```
<Target Name="custom step" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">

    <AsyncExec Command="powershell.exe sleep 2;powershell.exe -file xxxxx"></AsyncExec>
          
</Target>
```

The sleep time is up to the the size of your project and how long it takes to publish the folder.

And this function works well in my side.

Comment: Yes it works. Great. Thanks a ton.  `<Target Name="AfterPublish" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">   
    <AsyncExec Command="powershell.exe sleep 20;powershell.exe Start iexplore.exe "></AsyncExec>   
  </Target>`

Comment: just to clarify again `sleep 2` - 2 is seconds right ?

Comment: Sure. It means the second. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.1).